# Search keyword query not working as expected when searching for item that contains - in it

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, sharepoint-search, query

I have mapped a column to `RefinableString01` which I am using to search for an item.

When searching for `RefinableString01="test"` It will bring back the result. but when I search for `RefinableString01="test-1"` it doesn't bring back any result.

However using `RefinableString01:"test-1"` brings back the expected result.

I however don't want to use `:` instead of `=` as `:` will bring back items that are named test and test-1 when I search for `RefinableString01="test"`.

Is there a reason why the search query doesn't work when it contains `-` in it?

Comment: hyphens is considered as word breaker in SP search. Is it works if search for `RefinableString01="test 1"` ?

Comment: RefinableString01="test 1" works fine. I have other environment where RefinableString01="test-1" query is working. So idk why it's not working for some environment and not for another.

Comment: which sharepoint version you are using for "this" and "another" environment?